# How to stitch together 360 video

Tags: 360-video

I have a video that is 360 degrees  across and approximately 30 degrees vertically.  Is there a way I can stitch this into a 360 video view-able with google cardboard or something similar?

Comment: What do you have in mind for filling in the remaining portion of the view that's absent from your source? Padding the area above and below with black or some type of stationary graphic?

Comment: I was considering black.